# Is it possible to inject dependency to parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, masstransit

In X class, I have the following code block, and I'm facing with "*'QueueConsumer' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TConsumer' in the generic type or method 'ConsumerExtensions.Consumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator, Action<IConsumerConfigurator>)'*" error.

```
cfg =>
{
     cfg.Host(ServiceBusConnectionString);
     cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(router.Name, e =>
     {
         e.Consumer<QueueConsumer>(); // I got the error in this line
     });
 }
```

In QueueConsumer, I use IConfiguration class with dependency injection. I know, if I use empty constructor I won't see above error but then I can't use IConfiguration. This is my QueueConsumer  class:

```
public class QueueConsumer : IConsumer<TransferMessage>
{
    public readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public QueueConsumer(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
```

So, do you any idea for how to avoid this problem? How can I use dependency injection with parameterless constructor?

Comment: What are `ReceiveEndpoint` and `Consumer`? If you're using some kind of framework here, you should say what it is.

Comment: Sometimes parameterless constructors are required for Serializing. If you want, make a private parameterless constructor and chuck some breakpoints to see if your injected constructor is being hit.

Comment: You can use property injection, but you haven't told us what DI framework, (if any), you are using. Looks like the native one from .net/asp.net core?

Comment: Sorry guys, I am a newbie in .NET, any spesific DI framework wasn't used. `ReceiveEndpoint` and `Consumer` are coming from Masstransit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masstransit supports [factories](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/consumers.html#consumer-factories) for the consumer:

Taken from the above link:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("order-service", e =>
{
    // delegate consumer factory
    e.Consumer(() => new SubmitOrderConsumer());

    // another delegate consumer factory, with dependency
    e.Consumer(() => new LogOrderSubmittedConsumer(Console.Out));

    // a type-based factory that returns an object (specialized uses)
    var consumerType = typeof(SubmitOrderConsumer);
    e.Consumer(consumerType, type => Activator.CreateInstance(consumerType));
});
```

So you can inject any dependency you want here. You should also be able to use whatever DI Framework you want in/as such a factory method.

However, if you are using ASP.Net Core DI, please read the following for the integration that MassTransit has built in:
https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using MassTransit with RabbitMQ and vanilla DI for ASP.NET Core in this case you can do it.

1. You might need to add NuGet `MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection`
2. When configuring services with `AddMassTransit` you need to use `AddConsumer[s]`
3. When configuring rabbit with `UsingRabbitMq` you need to use `ConfigureConsumer`

The final code might look similar to this (a snippet for hosted service in .Net 6)

```
// some code above
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddMassTransit(
    opt =>
    {
        // Add all consumers from the assembly
        opt.AddConsumers(typeof(CoolConsumer).Assembly);
        opt.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            // Spin up the RabbitMQ bus with values from config
            cfg.Host(hostContext.Configuration["RabbitMQ:Host"],
                hostContext.Configuration["RabbitMQ:VirtualHost"], h =>
                {
                    h.Username(hostContext.Configuration["RabbitMQ:Username"]);
                    h.Password(hostContext.Configuration["RabbitMQ:Password"]);
                });
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("my-queue-name", p =>
            {
                p.ConfigureConsumer<CoolConsumer>(context);                            
            });                        
        });
    });
});    
// some additional code
```